# unity3d prefab problems prefab does not occur

Tags: unity-game-engine

Adding Cube Prefab does not work.

Is the position of gameBoardCreator and gameBoardView wrong?
What is the problem?

[image: i add cubeprefab but does not work]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameBoardView : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private GameObject _cubePrefab;
    private GameBoard _gameBoard;

    public void SetGameBoard(GameBoard gameBoard)
    {
        _gameBoard = gameBoard;

        for (int col = 0; col < _gameBoard.Columns; col++)
        {
            for (int row = 0; row < _gameBoard.Rows; row++)
            {
                var position = new Vector3(col, 0, row);
                var instance = Instantiate(_cubePrefab, position, Quaternion.identity, transform);
            }
        }
    }
}


using UnityEngine;

public class GameBoardCreator : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int columns = 2;
    public int rows = 2;
    private void onEnable()
    {
        GameBoard gameBoard = new GameBoard(columns, rows);
        FindObjectOfType<GameBoardView>().SetGameBoard(gameBoard);
    }
}


public class GameBoard
    {
        public int currentColumn;
        public int currentRow;
        public bool[,] _positions;

        public readonly int Rows;
        public readonly int Columns;

        public GameBoard(int columns, int rows)
        {
            Columns = columns;
            Rows = rows;
            _positions = new bool[columns, rows];
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in "`onEnable`", which should be "`OnEnable`" to be invoked properly by the MonoBehaviour. Thus, your SetGameBoard function is never called. You may also consider moving that logic to `Start`. The [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html) of MonoBehaviour provides all the information about which function is called when.

Comment: Glad that your problem is solved. If you found this answer helpful, you may consider picking it as the answer to the problem and upvote so that other people who might face similar issues will see this on top.